# Is it possible with HTML, CSS, JS to use a HTML template and add to it in different HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html

So i have created a default template for a website and i want the rest to keep that design and add the content which they are supposed to have, in a specified place in the template.

I know it's possible with something like [django](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extends-django-template-tags/), but can i do it with only HTML, JS, CSS copying the template content to every HTML?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: you could use something like mustache.js https://github.com/janl/mustache.js it allows you to declare templates, passing data and render https://jsfiddle.net/onj03158/1/

Comment: I am not sure if you understand the concept of server-side and client-side? You have no access to your server side html files from the browser where the javascript is executed. But what you can do is load the html from the server using AJAX and then put the content in the current html document. At this point i would recommend a frontend library which handles templating for you. (reactjs, vuejs, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes! It is possible with only Javascript. Though using jQuery will be much more easier.

Let's say if you wanted to load other html into a div.

### Javascript (using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)):

```
document.getElementById("add-stuff-inside").innerHTML = await (await fetch('/path_to_html/html_file_name.html')).text();
```

### jQuery:

- $.get()
- $.load()