# Load HTML file into a webpage's HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, include

I am building a webpage that loads the functional scripts ( e.g. script.js ) during onload. This script have functionalities such as timer, and user activity tracking ( Tracking whether user is on Page, Inactive on the page). **If the user is actively on the page for 10 seconds, It will show a pop out survey window and allow users to fill in** similar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Un4.png)

How could I finish this by **just using JavaScript to load the HTML and CSS of this pop out window** from a source?
For example:

popUpWindow.html

```
<div>
 <form> ... </form>
</div>
```

I imagine that these codes can be inserted into the webpage's DOM and shows up when necessary like this:
webpageScript.js

```
// functionalities for user and timer tracking here

function loadPopOutWindow() {
  // download the html and css source files of the window 
  // include the tags of html file into webpage's html
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = ...;
}
```

webpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   ...
 </head>
 <body>
   // Webpage's contents 

   // pop out window 
   <div>
     <form> ... </form>
   </div>
   // apply the style of the pop out window 
   <style .. ></style>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried to google search around to figure out other ways to implement this. I am not suggesting to use ways like load it using other language like PHP. If my idea is impossible, I also seen there are ways to do this using jQuery but is it possible to include jQuery codes using vanilla javascript?

Note: My webpage is built with HTML, CSS and vanilla javascript

Comment: The modal can be loaded at the same time when the entire page is loaded but with its `display` set to `none`. Later when the timer goes off, toggle the `display` to show it up

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Refer to my answer given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089435/9499523