# Replacing a Specific Code of Block in HTML with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to replace block of codes in a bunch or just single HTML file. I'd like to get the specific block only. How could I do that?

Supposed to have this HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background: lightblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I'd like to read the file and get the block of `<body>` tag only and replace it with another block of `<body>` tag. I don't want to get the other block.

How can I achieve it with Vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refer to my answer provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089435/9499523).

To accomplish what you wanted, I will simply provide an example for this.

For example you have 2 HTML files.

```
<!-- This is main.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background: lightblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!-- This is replace.html -->
<h1>This is some messages to be replacing the original boday section</h1>
<p>You may use FETCH API to do it....</p>
<p>blablablabla.....</p>
```

Lets say you would like to load the content of replace.html into main.html's body, you can use javascript FETCH API on the main.html to do it as below:

```
document.body.innerHTML = await (await fetch('/replace.html')).text();
```

It's just that simple and easy. Good luck!

*Tips: Your replace.html can only consists of the elements you wanted, you dont necessarily need the `<html>`/`<head>`/`<body>` tags. These only needed on your main.html.